# Differentiating static routes with variable routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.4

I actually want to define an explicit route. Let me give up an example.

```
Route::get('/profile/{slug}', function(){...});
```

This route is used to view profile of user.

But similarly I want to define -

```
Route::get('/profile/edit', function(){...});
```

to display edit profile view.

I'm not able to implement it because its sending '**edit**' as a value to `{slug}`.

How should I implement this while keeping both the routes in same group with same middleware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to interchange lines as below.

```
Route::get('/profile/edit', function(){...});
Route::get('/profile/{slug}', function(){...});
```

First it will check for `edit` else it will be passed to `slug`.

Comment: Wow. Actually I didn't expect that to work but surprisingly its working. How is it so? Does it add any exception to upcoming routes?

Comment: You was having first route as `/profile/{slug}` that's why application was treating anything after`/profile/*` as `slug`. Because of this your other routes were never called. (like `/edit`)

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot though.